# Applying horizontal dots in a LaTeX Quantum Circuit diagram

Tags: quantum-circuit, qaoa

I am almost done with my circuit diagram for the QAOA circuit but the \cdots does not want to cooperate. As seen there exists some wire drawn across the dots from the gate to the right and I can't seem to figure out why this is the case or how I get rid of it. Maybe I am using this command incorrectly, any thoughts would help greatly!

My TeX result:
[image]

My TeX code:

```
\Qcircuit @C = 0.3em @R = 0.6em{
\lstick{|0\rangle} & \gate{H} & \multigate{4}{e^{-i\gamma_1H_C}} & \multigate{4}{e^{-i\beta_1H_M}} & \cdots & \multigate{4}{e^{-i\gamma_pH_C}} & \multigate{4}{e^{-i\beta_pH_M}} & \meter & \cw\\
\lstick{|0\rangle} & \gate{H} & \ghost{e^{-i\gamma_1H_C}} & \ghost{e^{-i\beta_1H_M}} & \cdots & \ghost{e^{-i\gamma_pH_C}} & \ghost{e^{-i\beta_pH_M}} & \meter & \cw\\
\lstick{|0\rangle} & \gate{H} & \ghost{e^{-i\gamma_1H_C}} & \ghost{e^{-i\beta_1H_M}} & \cdots &  \ghost{e^{-i\gamma_pH_C}} & \ghost{e^{-i\beta_pH_M}} & \meter & \cw\\
\lstick{\vdots \ }  &  \pureghost{e^{-i\gamma_1H_C}} & \pureghost{e^{-i\beta_1H_M}} &  & \pureghost{e^{-i\gamma_pH_C}}  & \pureghost{e^{-i\beta_pH_M}}  &  \pureghost{} & \vdots & \\
\lstick{|0\rangle} & \gate{H} & \ghost{e^{-i\gamma_1H_C}} & \ghost{e^{-i\beta_1H_M}} & \cdots &  \ghost{e^{-i\gamma_pH_C}} & \ghost{e^{-i\beta_pH_M}} & \meter & \cw \\
}
```

Comment: Consider to ask on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is related to LaTeX issue in Qiskit and not directly to quantum computing.